# Cannot access nested many-to-many has_many :through associations from parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, collections, many-to-many, has-many-through

EDIT: This may help get to the point of my question...

Is there a way to do "cascading" through: associations? For example, if we go with the bones song: "The foot bone is connected to the ankle bone, the ankle bone's connected to the leg bone, the leg bone's connected to the hip bone..." I don't want to say that the foot has_many hipbones, because that's not entirely accurate. Nor do I want to say the foot has_many hipbones through the legbone (because it also needs to pass through the ankle). No instead, the foot has_many hips through the ankle which is through the leg. The foot is connected to an ankle, and that foot_ankle assembly is then connected to a leg, and then that entire foot_ankle_leg assembly is finally attached to a hip. So a foot can have many hips, but the foot doesn't belong to a hip in isolation, the association exists only as part of a particular foot_ankle_leg assembly.

To represent something like this, am I correct in setting up those inbetween through tables to "carry" the foot/ankle/leg connections up to the hip? (ie The a_b_c_d_e table represents something akin to a "final" foot_ankle_leg_hip assembly)

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION: Have several models that come together with various intervening many-to-many :through tables. HABTM is not used since these through tables contain additional attributes.

Here's an image of how it fits together, green boxes are the many-to-many join tables. For brevity's sake, renamed to letters

[image: Database chart]

Here's how the structure is coded

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :a_bs
  has_many :bs, through: :a_b
...
end

class B < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :a_bs,
  has_many :as, through: :a_b
...
end

class AB < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :b
  has_many :a_b_c_ds
  has_many :c_ds, through: :a_b_c_d
...
end

class C < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :c_ds
  has_many :ds, through: :c_d
...
end

class D < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :c_ds
  has_many :cs, through: :c_d
...
end

class CD < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :c
  belongs_to :d
  has_many :a_b_c_ds
  has_many :a_bs, through: :a_b_c_d
...
end

class ABCD < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a_b
  belongs_to :c_d
  has_many :a_b_c_d_es
  has_many :es, through: :a_b_c_d_e
...
end

class E < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :a_b_c_d_es
  has_many :a_b_c_ds, through: :a_b_c_d_e
...
end

class ABCDE < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a_b_c_d
  belongs_to :e
...
end
```

Whenever I try to access nested children from the parent object in the console, something like `A.first.a_b_c_ds`, it returns

`#<ABCD::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x26ca578>`.

Is this what I should be seeing? Do I need to interact with that CollectionProxy directly rather than see the "usual" records output? If so, that's a new thing I'll need to learn about :)

In the read-out, I also notice that it's attempting to find the parent's id in the through table rather than the "child" id that's associated.

```
ABCD Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "a_b_c_ds".* FROM "a_b_c_d" WHERE "a_b_c_d"."a_id" = ?  [["a_id", 1]]
```

Now, obviously, the `a_id` won't be in table ABCD. But `ab_id` is in there, which ***is*** associated with `a_id`. And if I'm reading the rails-guide correctly, rails should be smart enough to make that distinction if I set it up properly.

Any idea where I'm taking a wrong turn?

The class names aren't necessarily alphabetical. For example, Wrapping, Package, Object, WrappingPackage, WrappingPacakgeObject. But since I'm using named many-to-many through: tables, it's my understanding the table names shouldn't matter. That it only comes into play when using has_many_and_belongs_to join tables. But is that where I'm off?

Thanks for your help! Let me know if you need more snippets!

Comment: Your example: `A.first.a_b_c_ds` seems wrong, there is no `a_b_c_ds` association in A.

Comment: Ahhh, okay! So if I'm hearing you correctly, associations don't automatically stack or cascade like Class inheritance? The associations have to be explicitly defined up and down the "data chain" per se?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each belongs_to or has_many call creates an association method in all instances of the class.

So when you do:

```
class A
    has_many bs
end

class B
    has_many cs
end
```

then you basically added method `bs` to all A's instances. There is no method `cs` in A and there is no other magic involved.

Comment: Okay that makes sense! So, is there a way to do like a double through or triple through?  For example, if we go with the bones song: "The foot bone is connected to the ankle bone, the ankle bone's connected to the leg bone, the leg bone's connected to the hip bone..." I don't want to say that the foot has_many hipbones. Nor do I want to say the foot has_many hipbones through the legbone (because it also needs to pass through the ankle). To represent something like this, am I correct in setting up those inbetween through tables to "carry" the foot/ankle/leg connections up to the hip?